# MySQL INSERT AFTER Trigger to Copy Row to Another Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running MySQL 5.6 and I have two databases.  When a record is inserted into the table of one database, I want to insert that row into the same table in the other database.  I have this working properly.

My question, is there a shorthand reference to just insert the whole new row into the other database's table.  Short-hand so I don't have to write all the column names and VALUES().  I'd like to simplify the trigger so that when I update the table (add/remove/rename columns), I don't need to update the Trigger's SQL code too.

Something like this (this won't work, but gets the point across), that copies the new row from database "abc" to database "def"

```
CREATE TRIGGER abc.users_insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT
ON abc.users FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO def.users NEW;
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html is this what you are doing to replicate the database?

Comment: No, it's only the users table that I want to keep in sync between the two databases. All the other tables in the databases will be independent.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-rules-table-options.html you can set up replication at a table level as well